# How to save NOW() to the same field in my Laravel Eloquent model every time I save?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Every time I perform the following:

```
$user = new User;
$user->name = 'John';
$user->save();
```

I want a field called "modified" to be updated to `NOW()` in MySQL. I can't use Laravel's timestamps because I'm only using a single modified field. I could rely on MySQL to do this for me, but I was wondering if there was a way to accomplish this in my Laravel model? Perhaps using a mutator in some way to set this before saving?

*As a bonus:* how would I do something like this `$user->modified = "NOW()"`? (which is obviously wrong, but hopefully demonstrates the point)

Comment: I guess you could `SELECT NOW()` and assign that.

Comment: yeah but that's an extra query

Comment: Yes, it is an extra query. You could use PHP's `time()` if the timezone etc is set the same as the MySQL install.

Comment: Yep!, @Marty thought of that too, but still defeats my goal for the question. Need a way to plug those MySQL constants/functions like `NOW()` in there.

Comment: @Prix I'm only using one column. So I have `public $timestamps = false;` in my models.

Comment: By default is updates 2 fields (one for create date, one for modified date). I only keep one field in my tables.

Comment: But this question could further provide a solution as to how we can get non-parameterized / non-quoted values (like NOW) into the query (without using a db::raw call)

Comment: You can't get values from the database without querying it, PHP doesn't provide a layer of methods that magically give you values that MySQL is meant to provide.

Comment: @Prix that will pass the string "NOW()" and not the MySQL NOW() function. @Marty I'm not sure what you are saying? In a simple PDO query we can say `users.modified = NOW()`, this is all I'm trying to do via setting a property or adding some code to do this in a method in the model somewhere.

Comment: Note that you said a simple PDO *query*. A query is involved here, which is the case for getting the value of `NOW()` as well.

Comment: Well, I'd love to quote you @Marty as I've been saying to so many folks how I think ORMs just don't work for complex projects. But nonetheless, attempting to avoid a raw query here.

Comment: @Prix I don't really want to keep fields in the database that aren't being used. Simple as that. Keeping all the growing data in memory is very important for fast querying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can accomplish this in the `saving` event, for which you can register a callback in you model's `boot` method:

```php
class User extends Eloquent {

    public static function boot()
    {
        static::saving(function($user)
        {
            $user->modified = DB::raw('NOW()');

            // Alternatively, you can use this:
            $user->modified = Carbon\Carbon::now();
        });

        parent::boot();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hooray! Also solves a problem of where I wanted to add the session'd user to a `modified_by` field! `$user->modified_by = Auth::user()->id;`

Comment: @DavidGraham Doesn't this answer conflict with your comment: `But this question could further provide a solution as to how we can get non-parameterized / non-quoted values (like NOW) into the query (without using a db::raw call)`?

Comment: *could* (see bonus in question)

Comment: but also notice the use of `db::raw` here is not for running a raw query

Comment: Checked it! It works! `$user->modified = DB::raw("NOW()");` works. But I do see how my comment could be confusing @Marty I was referring to a full raw query `DB::select(DB::raw...` query

Comment: @DavidGraham I assumed `::raw` ran straight SQL on-demand (e.g. returned the value of `NOW()` in this instance). I am not familiar enough with Laravel to know whether that's the case or not.

Comment: No prob Marty, I +1 you. You are like me in that you don't just read a question mechanically, but think about it organically (in trying to see if there is a solution that still accomplishes the potential goal)

Comment: @DavidGraham - If you don't want to use `DB::raw`, just set it to a date object: `$user->modified = Carbon\Carbon::now()`

Comment: No I was just trying to avoid a raw query. Simply using the DB::raw is not an issue actually I realized.